# Sensitive data in Hidden field

Tags: forms, hidden-field

Is it good practice to put the Sensitive Data like cart price or user balance information in Form hidden field and process the form.

```
<input name="usr_bal" id="usrBal" value="9.0" type="hidden">
```

I think its vulnerable since the value can be altered by inspecting the browser. My problem is I get the balance information of a user from database and do some calculation and send the calculated value to database. For now I am using hidden field and its a Rails application. So, please suggest me if there is any other way to protect the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea - as you correctly pointed out, it can be easily altered. Generally, you want to store sensitive info on the server side (with some stuff never leaving the database, like login credentials, for instance).

Comment: Its not a good idea. But my problem is that I gets a value form database and do some calculation on client side and send the calculated value to the server side.

Comment: How do you get the value from the database on the client side? It's an XHR call directly to the database somehow?

Comment: Using database search

Comment: Please provide more info about your setup. I am not sure what "using database search" means in this context. Typically, databases are server-side entities; you'd get values into ASP.NET, Web API, or PHP code, or similar - some back-end (server-side) entity, before passing it to the client. Can't it stay server-side and the calculations be done there?

Comment: A merchant search the customer using the customer id, its a rails application. Merchant does some calculation with customer, its handled by jQuery and submits the calculated value.

Comment: Interesting. I am not familiar with rails enough to advise, but there's got to be a way to avoid client-side involvement in this process; for instance, call a server-side method that kicks in the merchant search process and handles the data there. It would avoid storing sensitive info client side.